# Como não converter um numero exponencial para decimal?

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Galera estou tendo o seguinte problema:

Criei uma função para colocar o(s) ponto(s) de milhar nos valores que recebe como parâmetro (VARCHAR2). Esta função recebe valores inteiro e valores do tipo VARCHAR ('Algum texto').
Quando o valor não é inteiro ou não é maior que 999 retorna **exatamente** o valor que entrou.
O problema é que quando recebe um número em exponencial a função converte para VARCHAR e deixa de ser expresso em exponencial. Ex:

```
SQL> SELECT pontoMilhar2(1E-2) nTratado FROM dual;
```

Retorna ,01. O que deveria retornar era **1E-2**, porque não é maior que 999.
Assim que entra na função o valor ja fica ,01.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pontoMilhar2 (inValor IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
BEGIN
   IF isFloat (inValor) = 1
   THEN
      IF inValor > 999
      THEN
         RETURN pontoMilhar1(inValor);
      ELSE
         RETURN inValor;
      END IF;
   ELSE
      RETURN inValor;
   END IF;

   RETURN inValor;
END pontoMilhar2;
```

OBS: Coloquei esse pontoMilhar1 porque daí pra frente funciona perfeito.

Prgunta: 
Existe algum parâmetro de entrada que não faça essa conversão??

Comment: Publica a pontoMilhar1

Comment: Um detalhe, a função vai SEMPRE converter para varchar2, que é o tipo de dados de definiste como parametro. Uma sugestão para permitir enviar um numero ou varchar, é recorrer a overload the função (basicamente, ter 2 funções com o mesmo nome, mas a receberem tipos de dados diferentes) , com packages. Apesar de eu não ser muito fâ, acho que é uma situação válida para ti.